# How to arrange a rowise data coming from hql query into columns based upon particular condition in JRXML

Tags: jasper-reports

My hql query in JRXML file takes out data rowwise from a table. From this data I need to display some records as columns based upon particular condition.
For example I get data as below: 
Subtopic1_Down_1

Subtopic1_Down_2

Subtopic1_Up_1

Subtopic1_Up_2

Subtopic1_Up_3

Currently my jrxml helps me to display data one after another dividing the data with group expression = value of subtopic. All Subtopic1_Down records together in one table. Followed by Subtopic1_Up records in next table and so on for remaining subtopics.

**Subtopic1_down**

Subtopic1_down_1

Subtopic1_down_2

**Subtopic1_Up**

Subtopic1_Up_1

Subtopic1_Up_2

Subtopic1_Up_3

But now I want the data to be displayed in such a way that all Subtopic1_Down and Subtopic1_Up records should be displayed in table but different columns as below:

**Subtopic1**

**Down**                                 **Up**

Subtopic1_Down_1                     Subtopic1_Up_1

Subtopic1_Down_2                     Subtopic1_Up_2

How can I achieve it through Jrxml?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of scriptlets to modify the resultset row-wise data into column at run time.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Could you please explain how it can be done through some example?

Comment: [Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jasper_reports/jasper_report_scriptlets.htm) is the tutorial link for scriptlet in jasper reports. 
[Here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/blog/all-you-want-know-about-scriptlets) is the jasper community tutorial.
[Here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/scriptlet/) is the sample scriptlet.